# return with shortcuts < && || >

Tags: javascript

I'am trying to use return together with shortcuts.

```
window.abc=window.abc || console.log("works fine");
```

or

```
window.cde=window.cde && console.log("works fine");
```

but if I use return instead console I will get an error.

```
window.abc=window.abc && return;
```

Is there a trick or an explanation?

Comment: if you are using this line in a function, show the full function, you cann't write `return` outside a function.

Comment: Producing a syntax error is not a trick. It is an explanation though...

Comment: Unless you're just playing with javascript, if you don't master these things, please prefer code readability to _shortcuts_ .

Comment: `window.cde= window.cde && console.log("works fine");` will assign `undefined` to `window.cde` if it prints stuff. Are you sure you know what you are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log()` is an expression and can be used as part of other expressions or statements.
`return` is a statement and cannot be used as part of another statement or expressions.

You can do:

```
return .. || ..;

if (..)
    return ..;
```

You cannot do:

```
.. && return;
```

Comment: that means it's always "if (window.abc=window.ab) return;" no shortcut?

Comment: Yes, no shortcut. That's already pretty darn concise, not sure how much shorter you need it to be... ;)

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is that return is not an expression that you can OR or AND. 
It does not yield the value. It's a statement.

You probably mean to use conditional branch instead:

```
if (window.abc)
  return;
```

If you are in the global scope, and want, for example, as you noted in the comment,
to discard the rest of the script file, you just need to wrap everything in (anonymous) function.

```
(function() {
   // ...
   if (window.abc)
     return;
   // ...
})();
```

Comment: I would like to test if a function is declared in windows. If yes I would like to stop loading a script-file.

Comment: @hamburger: now I see what you're trying to gain, updated the answer above.